# How to generate the script template elements in a node-red html file

Tags: node-red

I'm looking for a way to generate, ideally from the `<script type="text/javascript">` section, the `<script type="text/html">` sections of a [node-red node html definition file](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/node-html).

**Background context**

I'm creating a large number of node-red nodes to access and/or serve an API. The API follows similar patterns for the different resource that it represents, like you'd expect from a REST API. This results in a lot of similar looking nodes like: `get-book-action`, `get-publisher-action`, `get-author-action`, and so on for each of the methods and resources the API exposes.

I've written my node-red node in such a way that I can simply define the list of resources (i.e. `const resources = ['book', 'author', 'series', 'publisher', ...]`) and have it loop through creating the specific nodes for `get`, `update`, etc. The thing I haven't worked out yet is how to do the same for the editor template sections, which is why I'm asking this question.

**Pseudo example**

I'd like something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(RED) {
  const resources = ["author", "book", "publisher", ...];
  resources.forEach(resource => {
    RED.nodes.registerType(`get-${resource}-action`, {...});
    RED.nodes.registerType(`update-${resource}-action`, {...});
    RED.nodes.registerType(`delete-${resource}-action`, {...});
    // other verbs

    // some api to create the editor template script tags
    document.write(`
      <script type="text/html" data-template-name="get-${resource}-action">
        <div class="form-row">
          <label for="node-config-input-name><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="node-config-input-name">
        </div>
      </script>`);
    // and so on for the other verbs/node types and template types like data-help-name
  });
})(RED);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script blocks in the `.html` file of a node-red node simply get inserted into the dom as a child of a div on the editor page. This means that you have the full power of the front-end JavaScript to work with.

The way I found to accomplish this is with something like the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(RED) {
  const resources = ["author", "book", "publisher", ...];
  resources.forEach(resource => {
    RED.nodes.registerType(`get-${resource}-action`, {...});
    RED.nodes.registerType(`update-${resource}-action`, {...});
    RED.nodes.registerType(`delete-${resource}-action`, {...});
    // other verbs

    // We have to split up the <scr and ipt parts as if either the opening or closing
    // tags appear anywhere in this block it will close the js script block
    $(document.currentScript).parent().append(
      '<scr'+`ipt type="text/html" data-template-name="get-${resource}-action">
        <div class="form-row">
          <label for="node-config-input-name><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="node-config-input-name">
        </div>
      </scr`+'ipt>'
    );
    // and so on for data-help-name and other verbs
  });
})(RED);
</script>
```